# Place two ImageViews programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to place multiple new ImageViews in my layout. The problem is that one comes on top of another exactly at the same location. Although I change the location, it only relates to the first one. They both are at 80,80.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    addpPicD(lp1,80,80);
    addpPicD(lp1,100,100);
}

private void addpPicD(LayoutParams lp, int Lan, int Lon) 
{

        lp.setMargins(Lan, Lon, 0, 0);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);  
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.dot_bl);  
        imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        rel.addView(imageView);

}
```

Comment: As an end result, how would you like them placed? Side by side horizontally? One under another?

Comment: I would you like them placed at their position. One at 80,80 and other at 100,100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you set the layoutparams the first time you create the layout and then they aren't recreated as you would think they would be.

Simple solution. Change it to the code below which works as tested by me:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = null;

addpPicD(lp1,80,80);
addpPicD(lp1,100,100);
}

private void addpPicD(LayoutParams lp, int Lan, int Lon) 
{
    lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.setMargins(Lan, Lon, 0, 0);
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);  
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.dot_bl);  
    imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
    rel.addView(imageView);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

`RelativeLayout` has its own [`Layout Parameters`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html). To place child views side by side, or vertically you will need to provide  rules. Use [`addRule()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#addRule%28int,%20int%29) on layout parameters of each view you add.

Pass values like `RelativeLayout.BELOW`, `RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF` etc along with the `id` of view with which you want to align with.