# Positioning ImageView in two lines programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I have a code which generate several ImageView and put it on Layout.

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_MATCHES; i++) {
        imageView = new ImageView(this);
        if (random.nextBoolean()) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.match);
        } else {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.match_inverse);

        }
        gameLinearLayout.addView(imageView, 0, params);
    }
```

But all images are in one line. I want to place it in two lines. Which layout to use and how to fix code for working correctly?

Comment: Try out with `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want 2 seperate rows of images.
So we need a base LinerLayout with a vertical orientation to hold each row, while each row consists of a LinerLayout with a horizontal orientation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/row1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/row2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

look here for explanation why it is happening:

[Place two ImageViews programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032616/place-two-imageviews-programmatically?rq=1)

and look here for explanation to the last answer in this thread which talking about RelativeLayout Rules:

[How to set RelativeLayout layout params in code not in xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191099/how-to-set-relativelayout-layout-params-in-code-not-in-xml/5191159#5191159)

Comment: Judging by the naming, he's using a LinearLayout, not a RelativeLayout.

Comment: oh, it seems you are correct, we need the xml code to see how he uses it though..

Answer (score 0):

Try out as below:

```
        //LinearLayOut Setup
        LinearLayout linearLayout= new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_MATCHES; i++) 
     {
        //ImageView Setup
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        //setting image resource
  if (random.nextBoolean()) {
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.match);
    } else {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.match_inverse);

    }

        //setting image position
        imageView.setLayoutParams(linearLayout);

        //adding view to layout
        linearLayout.addView(imageView);
 }
```